# Maintaining a single codebase between embedded and non-embedded code

Tags: c, testing, embedded, tdd, microcontroller

I'm working on a robotics research project that involves programming a microcontroller. I'd like to be able to decouple testing the software from testing the hardware to the greatest extent possible. This is both to increase development speed and also so that I can more easily unit test/simulate the code before putting it on the robot. So for example, I might write a "MyRobot" library. Then I could include this library both in the embedded code and my non-embedded simulation/testing code. At runtime, I'd provide function pointers that would either read (in the embedded case) or simulate (in the simulation) sensor data and feed that into the library.

So it seems like all I would need to do is generate two libraries at compile time: one for the embedded code, and one for the non-embedded code.

My question is whether or not this is feasible/if there are better ways to do it/if there are any gotcha's I should watch out for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Idea; Generate 3 codes bases, A_embedded, A_non-embedded and B_common.   Some code just makes no sense in the other world.

Comment: Right, that was my plan. Have one "common" library, and then two distinct applications/libraries that use the common one: one for embedded, and one for non-embedded

Comment: The key here will be to write all the code portable. It is fully possible to use the _same_ code on for example a resource-constrained MCU and a burdensome 64 bit Windows PC. This requires far more extensive C knowledge from the programmer though: integer limits, implicit type promotions, signedness, endianess, implementation-defined behavior etc etc all have to be considered. You might want to consider using some flavour of MISRA-C to weed most of such portability vulnerabilities through static analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common situation in embedded systems development, and your approach of creating two libraries is usually the recommended solution. It's considered a best practice to decouple the low-level hardware from the software in embedded systems firmware.

The library you mentioned is commonly known as a *"Hardware Abstraction Layer"*, or HAL. The API (application programming interface) for the HAL can be provided in a single header file named something like `hal.h`. Every source module in your software that needs to access the hardware would have the following line at the top of the source file:

```
#include "hal.h"
```

Benefits of designing your system like this include:

- **Modularity**. If you need to make a timing change on, say a UART or SPI interface that reads a sensor, you only need to change the HAL library even though there may be multiple locations in your code that read that sensor.
- **Portability**. If you later need to migrate your project to a different microcontroller, only the HAL layer would need to change.
- **Encapsulation**. The details of the hardware are hidden within the HAL layer, which allows your other software to operate at a higher level of abstraction. If you are using a device library provided by the microcontroller manufacturer that provides the addresses of registers, I/O ports, etc., you can encapsulate the references to this library within your HAL library, so that your application code need have no knowledge of it.
- **Testability**. This was the primary focus of your question. You can write a special version of the HAL layer that can be run on a different platform (such as Windows, for example) for testing of your application software. This special version would not need to include the device library provided by the microcontroller manufacturer, because when you are running in the test environment, the microcontroller doesn't exist, so its registers and I/O ports don't need to be accessed by your software.

For your two scenarios, as you suggested, you would create two versions of the HAL library: the standard version that contains the code that runs on your embedded hardware, and the simulation version that simulates the hardware for the purpose of testing your software in a controlled manner. You might name the standard library `hal.lib` (perhaps with a different extension depending on your development environment), and the simulation library `hal_simulated.lib`. Both would have the same interface, as described in `hal.h`. That is, both libraries would contain all functions declared in `hal.h`, such as `void halInit()`, `int halReadProximitySensor()`, etc.

Assuming your IDE supports `Release` and `Debug` configurations, you could create a third configuration for your software testing that is named `SW_Test`. This configuration would be a duplicate of your `Debug` configuration, except that the `hal_simulated.lib` would be linked into the project instead of the standard `hal.lib`.

**See also**

[Hardware Abstraction (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the detailed response.

Comment: Overall good advise, but I wouldn't recommend to dump all drivers into one single library with a common header, because that turns everything project-specific. The problem with that is that you create a tight coupling between every single hardware driver: they all need the header. Which in turn means that in order to use your SPI driver on a project that only needs SPI, you must also provide the UART driver etc just so that things will link. It is better to create each module autonomous, with each own HAL. You'll have a SPI HAL and one UART HAL and they don't know about each other at all.

Comment: @Lundin: Those are details relating to how the HAL library is created. The OP needs a HAL for his project, so yes, it should be project-specific.  `hal.h` is the interface between the HAL library and the application code that uses it. It does not need to be `#include`d in every module in the HAL library; it only needs to be included in the application source files that need to access the HAL.

Comment: @Lundin: This would address your concern about coupling:
`hal_uart.c` would contain the line `#include "hal_uart.h"`, but would know nothing about `hal_spi.h` or `hal.h`.
`hal.h` would contain the lines `#include "hal_uart.h"` and `#include "hal_spi.h"`.
The application source files would contain only the line `#include "hal.h"`. So my answer does not imply a tight coupling between all of the hardware drivers.

Comment: @sifferman I don't see how that solves anything. If `hal.h` includes `hal_spi.h`, then you must always include the SPI driver in the project whenever you wish to use `hal.h` for completely unrelated UART purposes. That's still a dependency that shouldn't be there. That's ok if `hal.h` is some kind of project-specific summary of all used drivers, but in that case it should be named something else, like `robot_project.h` or whatever.

Comment: @Lundin The project is for a robot. A robot has hardware, such as proximity sensors, stepper motors, and solenoids. The interface to that hardware can be provided in a HAL. Hopefully, that interface won't include terms like "UART" and "SPI" because a robot's user doesn't want to think in those terms. The OP wasn't asking how to create a multi-purpose HAL that can be used in different projects - he wants a HAL for his robot. If you don't like the name `hal.h`, fine, but `hal.h` works for me because it serves as a single, simple header file that provides access to the entire HAL for the robot.

Comment: I made a minor edit to my answer so as to be a little less dogmatic about the use of a single header file as the entry point to the HAL.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are stuck with C that is not an object oriented language, I would go to a single library with some internal logic or even `#ifdefs` (if performance is a must), something like:

```
bool turnOn()
{
   #ifdef DEV
       printf ("Turned On\n");
       return true;
   #endif

   #ifdef PROD
      return robot_command_turnOn();
   #endif
}
```

or

```
bool turnOn()
{
   if (inProduction())
      return robot_command_turnOn();

   printf ("Turned On\n");
   return true;
}
```

Or even better:

```
bool turnOn()
{
   printf ("Turned On\n");

   if (!inProduction())
        return true;

  return robot_command_turnOn();
}
```

There are several ways to do it. In my view I wouldn´t go for two libraries as I would need to keep in sync function signatures and versions and this can be a mess.

The secret is to build an **interface library** to your hardware (robot in case) and develop the library convering all possible interactions so that will keep a level of abstraction from the hardware layer.  That interface library can control if you are testing the unit (using a function like `inProduction()` above) and send the commands to hardware if allowed.

Using an objected oriented language like C++ you have patterns to help you out: ie: *interface pattern*, *factory pattern*, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by an "interface library"?

Comment: A library like you said: robotlib.c - we can it an interface library because it contains only functions that will deal (interface) with your hardware.. ie: turnon(), turnoff(), stepup(), stepdown(), etc...

Comment: The "even better" version is not equivalent - it calls printf() unconditionally for all builds.